# setting anchor for "controls in a panel" inside a "flowlayoutpanel"

Tags: .net, vb.net, panel, windows, flowlayoutpanel

In my windows application

I have a normal panel inside a flowlayoutpanel

In this normal panel, i have some input controls(e.g. labels, textbox...)

I have set the anchor properties thinking that it will auto-resize when I resize the window.

But when i tested it, only the flowlayoutpanel auto-resize itself, as i can see that the sroll bar has moved further toward the right... the contorls in the normal panel didnt move at all.

anyone know what is wrong here?

Thank You!

Answer (score 5):

I have encountered the same problem. Apparently, the controls in the FlowLayoutPanel are sized according to the widest control in this panel. I've solved this by overriding the 'Resize' event on the FlowLayoutPanel and change one of the controls relative to the size of the FlowLayoutPanel:

```
private void RulesPanel_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FlowLayoutPanel panel = (FlowLayoutPanel)sender;
    button_in_panel.Width = panel.Width - 50;
}
```

Once one is set, the others are resized properly. This is also true for those that have Anchors specified.

Answer (score 1):

In the following post Lenny answered the question already

[cannnot-resize-child-controls-in-a-flowlayoutpanel-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844145/cannnot-resize-child-controls-in-a-flowlayoutpanel-control)

or this:

[flowlayoutpanel-issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694717/flowlayoutpanel-issues)

So i think theres no way.
For what exactley you need that control?

Comment: i am making a form which has got top(Panel A) and bottom(Panel B)... user can collapse panel A, therefore I placed these 2 panels in the flowlayout panel. When i set panel A visible off, panel B will automatically move up to fill the space... 


Hope someone can suggest me with an alternative for this case, Thank You!

Comment: My suggestion is to remove this control. And add a Function like VisibleChanged() There you can check if the panel is visible or not and set the position of your B Panel.<br> Now you can just call VisibleChanged() in the collapse function